# OleDbConnection vs AdomdConnection. I am able to connect to my cube using both the connections but wanted to know which is better

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssas, cube

Basically I want to know which one of is better for accessing cube using Analysis services.
My requirement is to fetch the data and display as drop down for filtering the reports.
I did POC for both the ways and both are working

Comment: this is not a programming question, no problem exists, you're on the wrong forum for this type of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We choose Adomd connection as it seems that is the standard way to access the cube. But I could not find any issues with OleDb also any inputs would be great. For now damn busy with the development work :)